# SpringData MongoDB Query on nested object and list object

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to find a `Type` document by the `code` of `job` and by the list of `code` of `category`, i tried the below query but it didn't work

```
@Document
public class Type {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private Job job;
    @DBRef
    private List<Category> categories;
}

public class Job {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String code;
}

public class Category {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String code;
}

public interface TypeRepository extends MongoRepository<Type, String> {
    @Query("{ 'job.code': ?0, 'category.code': { $in: ?1 }}")
    Type findByJobAndCategoriesCode(String codeJob, List<String> codeCategories);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this one

```
public interface TypeRepository extends MongoRepository<Type, String> {

    Type findOneByJobCodeAndCategoriesCodeIn(String codeJob, List<String> codeCategories);
}
```